# Is this a true statement about Brownian Motion?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $B$ denote Brownian motion started at 0. Given intervals $I_1=[a_1,b_1],..., I_n = [a_n,b_n]$ with $0<a_1,b_1<a_2$, $b_2<a_3$, ... $b_{n-1}<a_n$, let $y\geq 0$ and define

$$f(y) = P(\textrm{There exist } t_i\in I_i\textrm{ so that } B(t_i) = y\textrm{ for all } i).$$

My question is, is $f$ a decreasing function? To me, it seems like it should be true... But I have not been able to prove or disprove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you go into a little more detail? I don't see why that implies the general case.

Comment: Hmmm, I might have gone a little too fast here... Anyway, what I had in mind was the following decomposition. Let $T_y=\inf\{t\geqslant a_1\mid B(t)=y\}$, with PDF $g_y$, and, for every $I$, $A(I,y)$ the event that there exists $t$ in $I$ such that $B(t)=y$, then $$f(y)=\int_{a_1}^{b_1}h(t)g_y(t)dt$$ with $$h(t)=P(A(I_2,y)\cap\cdots\cap A(I_n,y)\mid B_t=y)$$ hence $$h(t)=P(A(I_2-t,0)\cap\cdots\cap A(I_n-t,0)\mid B_0=0)$$ which depends neither on $y$ nor on $I_1$. Thus, $f(y)$ depends on $y$ only through $g_y$ hence monotonicity properties of the latter might be all one needs.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar, the problem I'm having is in establishing monotonicity properties for $g_y$ that I can then pass to $f(y)$. The best I've been able to do is show 

$$\int_{a_1}^{b_1}g_y(t)$$ 

is decreasing in $y$, which I'm not sure is enough in general to show $f(y)$ is decreasing, as I don't have a good handle on $h(t)$. As far as pointwise monotonicity of $g_y$, I'm not sure that's possible, since the $g_y$ are positive and integrate to 1.

Comment: However, I've boiled down the problem to the following. For a fixed interval $I=[a,b]$ and $x>0$, let $m(y) = P_y(B\textrm{ has a zero in } I\textrm{ and } |B(b)|<x)$, so $m(y)$ is the probability that a Brownian motion started at $y$ has a zero in $I$, and that $B(b)$ lies in $(-x,x)$. If $m(y)$ is decreasing in $y$, then I believe I can show the original statement is true. It seems to me that showing $m(y)$ is decreasing might be a little more accessible too, at least I hope so.